# Minecraft crashes often, and often repeatedly until I force an update. Then it crashes again

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Regardless of when I crash, it's always the same console message that I see.

```
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at ic2.core.block.BlockMultiID.d(BlockMultiID.java:59)
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at ConnectedTextures.isNeighbour(ConnectedTextures.java:663) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at ConnectedTextures.getConnectedTextureVertical(ConnectedTextures.java:750) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at ConnectedTextures.getConnectedTexture(ConnectedTextures.java:265) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at ConnectedTextures.getConnectedTexture(ConnectedTextures.java:198) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at ConnectedTextures.getConnectedTexture(ConnectedTextures.java:154) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at bbb.k(RenderBlocks.java:2993)
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at bbb.b(RenderBlocks.java:7858)
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at WorldRendererThreaded.updateRenderer(WorldRendererThreaded.java:158) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at WrUpdateThread.run(WrUpdateThread.java:116) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already tesselating! 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at baz.b(Tessellator.java:504) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at baz.b(Tessellator.java:494) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at WorldRendererThreaded.updateRenderer(WorldRendererThreaded.java:128) 
2013-07-02 08:14:32 [INFO] [STDERR] at WrUpdateThread.run(WrUpdateThread.java:116) 
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already tesselating! 
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at baz.b(Tessellator.java:504) 
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at baz.b(Tessellator.java:494) 
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at azr.a(EffectRenderer.java:139) 
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at ban.a(EntityRenderer.java:1592)
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at ban.b(EntityRenderer.java:1117)
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.J(Minecraft.java:884) 
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:773)
2013-07-02 08:14:34 [INFO] [STDERR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
2013-07-02 08:14:44 [INFO] [STDOUT] Stopping! 
2013-07-02 08:14:45 [INFO] [STDOUT] SoundSystem shutting down... 
2013-07-02 08:14:45 [INFO] [STDOUT] Author: Paul Lamb, www.paulscode.com
```

Comment: Latest graphics drivers and Java version?

Comment: I tried to format this into a spoiler and couldnt get it to work, so I made it as easy on the eyes as possible. My apologies.

Comment: @tombull89 yes, ish. My java was updated the day before yesterday and my graphics card is years years old. It has the latest updates as I last knew, but far as I know they stopped releasing said updates for my card ages ago. I've got a Radeon Mobility HD 4250

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException implies code error (read: mod bug), or invalid dynamic bindings (read: too many mods).

Comment: And the ic2 at the second line points to industrialcraft2

Comment: @Zommuter thanks! how did you do that?

Comment: @FEichinger well I'm playing FTB, so yea there is a lot of mods, but... they are supposed to play nicely with eachother...

Comment: @Ender Select everything, then click on the `{}` icon (preformatted text). Easier than indenting every line manually by four spaces :-7 After all the site's enginge stems from the programmer's http://stackoverflow.com. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @Ender As I said, it could just as well be a code error, or *some* other error related to the way the mods are handled. I'm just saying it so we don't go for a goose hunt over hardware issues when that's most certainly *not* the case.

Comment: Since re-updating seems to fix this for a short while, I suspect there's a mod configuration file messing Minecraft up at some point. **edit** That connected texture messages - do you change an option to turn on/off connected textures once Minecraft works again?

Comment: This is a known issue with the Industrial Craft 2 mod. as shown here http://bt.industrial-craft.net/view.php?id=295. I suggest turning off connected textures (thats part of the issue) or updating ic2, or removing ic2 completely.

Comment: @RhysW please post that as an answer, you only fixed my problem, but you improved my FPS DRAMATICALLy/

Comment: @Ender sure thing, glad i could help!

Comment: @galacticninja wait so now we close questions that were off-topic at the time they were asked?

Comment: @Ender (I'm assuming that 'off-topic' is a typo of 'on-topic'.) Yes, I believe that's how meta consensus always worked - they're retroactive. Note that I didn't target this question specifically. I was also voting to close other Minecraft questions that I believe to be off-topic as per http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no - regardless of the date they were asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the same issue as yourself [here](http://bt.industrial-craft.net/view.php?id=295) on the IndustrialCraft 2 bug page.

You can tell it is an IC<sup>2</sup> issue because of line 2 of the error saying `ic2.core.block`

Some other mods, FTB included, also use the core part of the IC<sup>2</sup> mod, which might explain why some people will get the issue without knowingly installing the full IndustrialCraft mod.

What I can gather from this is that the version of IC<sup>2</sup> isn't able to properly map connected textures with a certain block type, which is why your issue appears intermittent yet always the same.

I suggest doing a combination of the following:

- Disable connecting textures
- Update to a later version of IC<sup>2</sup>  if one exists
- Disable IC<sup>2</sup>  and see if this stops the issue

Comment: Thanks for making your comment properly an answer! Here's a +1 to start the ball rolling.